# League \Flysystem \ UnableToCreateDirectory. 'Unable to create a directory at /...’ Storage::put, Laravel 10.17.1

Tags: image-upload, laravel-10

project is on macOS sonoma.

want to store image from webcam project https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-webcam-capture-image-and-save-from-camera-exampleexample.html (worked on standalone project)

next i want store string into db and store image on new file project this is code i currently use:

```
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`
```

also i’ve been trying using

```
`use Storage`
```

and this is code inside the function

```
//Image
        $img=$request->image;
        $folderPath=('upload/');

        $image_parts=explode(";base64",$img);
        $image_type_aux= explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
        $image_type=$image_type_aux[1];

        $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
        $fileName=$request->image.'.png';

        $file=$folderPath.$fileName;
        Storage::put($file,$image_base64);
     //String
        Product::create($request->all());
        
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('Success','Product created successfuly’);
```

here’s config filesystem

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
            'permissions' => [
                'file' => [
                    'public' => 0644,
                    'private' => 0600,
                ],
                'dir' => [
                    'public' => 0755,
                    'private' => 0700,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
            'permissions' => [
                'file' => [
                    'public' => 0644,
                    'private' => 0600,
                ],
                'dir' => [
                    'public' => 0755,
                    'private' => 0700,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

But in the end, it return error:
League\Flysystem\UnableToCreateDirectory

"Unable to create a directory at /[directory_name]”

been trying change root access and it didn’t work.
image upload into storage locally